# Dealing with a JSON object's property called "private" in C# with Newtonsoft's JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, xively

I am trying to parse a json string returned from the [xively](https://xively.com/) feed from an [Air Quality Egg](http://airqualityegg.com/). One of the properties says whether the xively feed is public or private. The property is called `private` and takes the string value "true" or "false". To get data from the feed I am calling xively's [Historical Data](https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/quick_reference/historical_data/) REST API which successfully returns me valid JSON. I am then using JSON.NET to parse the JSON in C#. My parsing starts thus:

```
dynamic historicalDatapoints  = JValue.Parse(jsonString) as JObject;
if (historicalDatapoints != null)
{
    var id = historicalDatapoints.id;
    var title = historicalDatapoints.title.ToString();
    var privacy = bool.Parse(historicalDatapoints.private.ToString())
    // More parsing
}
```

I have a problem with that last line of code. C# will not let me refer to the property called "private". Here's the corresponding (redacted) JSON:

```
{
    "id": 000000843,
    "title": "Blah Road Egg 02",
    "private": "false",
    //...
}
```

Using JSON.NET how should I parse out the property `private`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `historicalDatapoints.@private` to access that value. If that doesn't work then you could also try `historicalDatapoints["private"]`

Comment: That works! Thanks. I should have thought of the array access but the '@' qualifier is new to me (though I've used something similar on strings)